# naming collision while importing react module

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

I'm having trouble importing a module, not because it throws an error but because it breaks another part of my app.

I want to ...

```
import {NavBar,  ElementWrapper } from 'react-scrolling-nav';
```

.. but I have an existing module NavBar, that this import seems to break. I tried:

```
import {NavBar as ScrollingNavBar,  ElementWrapper } from 'react-scrolling-nav';
```

but it clobbered my existing NavBar. I tried:

```
import * as rscroll from 'react-scrolling-nav';
```

Is there a way to alias during import to avoid this situation?

Comment: even "import {ElementWrapper } from 'react-scrolling-nav';" breaks my page, but if I delete the line altogether it works

Answer (score 1):

The last option should work.

```
import * as rscroll from 'react-scrolling-nav';


const myNavBAr = rscroll.NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, as it turns out, the module I was trying to import was overriding my CSS, so it only looked like it was breaking my existing nav.